# Separate a specific end of a string into columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long list of filepaths in column A. I would like to cut out both the filename and the 2 nearest file paths into 3 separate columns (B, C, D). I would like to leave what is left of the file path in column A.

The depth is different on different rows. That is why it does not work with the standard splitting strings into columns based on a separator.

Here is an example of the data:

```
\\folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\Folder6\Filename.xxx
\\folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\Filename.xxx
\\folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Filename.xxx
```

Do you have any leads on how I can build this in VBA?

Comment: What "the 2 nearest file paths" means, please? `Folder5` and `folder6` for the first path?

Comment: My recommendation would be doing some fancy string manipulation with `split()`

Comment: Exactly. And then on other rows the dept is bigger or smaller. The depth is different on different rows. That is why it does not work with the standard splitting strings into columns based on a separator.

Comment: It works as I did it in my answer. If the "standard splitting" returns an array bigger than four elements... Does the code work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, please:

I choose to use B, C, D, E columns and you can delete A:A column if everything runs smooth. Or it is obvious how the code can be adapted to do exactly what you requested...

```
Sub testStrPath()
  Dim strAr As Variant, sh As Worksheet, i As Long, lastRow As Long
  Dim strPath As String
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your worksheet
  strAr = Split(strPath, "\")
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 1 To lastRow
    strPath = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
    strAr = Split(strPath, "\")
    If UBound(strAr) > 4 Then
        sh.Range("C" & i).Value = strAr(UBound(strAr) - 2)
        sh.Range("D" & i).Value = strAr(UBound(strAr) - 1)
        sh.Range("E" & i).Value = strAr(UBound(strAr))
        sh.Range("B" & i).Value = left(strPath, InStr(strPath, "\" & sh.Range("C" & i).Value) - 1)
    End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to here that! But I would like to remember that ticking the check box to the left side of the code, making it the chosen answer, did  not kill anybody until now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following formula as well.

Assuming your data starts in cell `A2` in cell `B2` write following formula.

`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"\",REPT(" ",99)),(LEN($A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"\",""))-COLUMNS(B$2:$D$2)+1)*99,99))`

Copy down and across.

The logic for the core formula is quite nicely explained here by Rick Rothstein

http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/333-Get-Field-from-Delimited-Text-String?s=0b13a52917f7e865e277885b0abfaa6f